# pgfkeys: allowing one key to activate another key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have two custom keys: `key1`, which is boolean; and `key2`, which accepts a value. The idea is that `key1` activates a feature, and `key2` customizes the feature. However, if `key2` is used, I want `key1` set to true automatically. So:

```
\tikzset{key2=3.5cm)
```

and

```
\tikzset{key1=true, key2=3.5cm}
```

should have the same effect.

All I need help with is making it so that `key1` is automatically set to true when `key2` is set to any value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name your original `key2` to `@key2` or any other internal name and define `key2` as follows:

```
\tikzset{key2/.style={key1=true, @key2={#1}})
```

This will pass the value to the internal key and also switch the boolean key on.